# turn off AKKA IO-TCP logging

Tags: tcp, io, akka

I want to turn off the logging of the following (lifecycle?) events, which configuration directive controls this?

```
DEBUG [akka://MyActorSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/371] - started (akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection@558309d8)
DEBUG [akka://MyActorSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/371] - now watched by Actor[akka://MyActorSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a#
DEBUG [akka://MyActorSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/371] - Attemptingconnection to [localhost/127.0.0.1:12002]
DEBUG [akka://MyActorSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/371] - Connection established to [localhost/127.0.0.1:12002]
DEBUG [akka://MyActorSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/371] - stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the lifecycle log messages ("started", "watched", "stopped") with the following setting in `application.conf`:

```
akka {
  actor {
    debug {
      # disable DEBUG logging of actor lifecycle changes
      lifecycle = off
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using remoting:

```
akka {
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
  }
}
```

The TCP connection log messages in your excerpt (which are set [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/io/TcpOutgoingConnection.scala#L80) and [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/io/TcpOutgoingConnection.scala#L96)) are hard-coded at the debug level and, unlike the lifecycle events, cannot be disabled. To prevent the logging of these messages, set your global logging level to a level that is more coarse-grained than debug (doing this also prevents the logging of lifecycle events, regardless of the above settings). More information on logging is found in the official [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html).